# Why Eclipse cannot recognize Feign dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-cloud-feign

I have this pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I run `mvn dependency:tree | findstr feign` I get

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign:jar:1.4.6.RELEASE:compile                                
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:1.4.6.RELEASE:compile                         
[INFO] |     +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:9.5.0:compile                                                        
[INFO] |     +- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:9.5.0:compile                                                       
[INFO] |     \- io.github.openfeign:feign-hystrix:jar:9.5.0:compile
```

But even I try using `import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;` as [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-eureka/spring-cloud-eureka-feign-client/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/cloud/feign/client/GreetingClient.java), I notice Eclipse/`mvn clean package -U` still doesn't recognize my dependency.

What possible configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using invalid cloud version. Below is sample working pom snippet. Maybe this will help you.

You can find working pom from this link. I have used Feign here with Ribbon.
https://github.com/ROBINSINGH0210/microservice-currency-service-spring-boot/blob/master/pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```